# In R, how can I merge two dataframes with different structures using a left_join?

Tags: r, join

I have two dataframes `df_1` and `df_2` with differing structures but I want to use a left_join to add columns from one df to the other.

My main df `df_1` looks like this:

```
structure(list(ID = c("131", "131", "206", "206", "5", "2"), 
    Company = c("ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "EFD", "SDF"), Name = c("Alex", 
    "Marian", "Peter", "Maria", "Mila", "Maya"), Degree = c("0", 
    "1", "1", "0", "1", "0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

ID   Company Name    Degree
131  ABC        Alex    0   
131  ABC        Marian  1   
206  DEF        Peter   1   
206  DEF        Maria   0   
5    EFD        Mila    1   
2    SDF        Maya    0
```

My second df `df_2` looks like this:

```
structure(list(ID = c("131", "206", "5", "2"), Company = c("ABC", 
"DEF", "EFD", "SDF"), Name_1 = c("Alex", "Peter", "Mila", "Maya"
), Name_2 = c("Marian", "Maria", NA, NA), Achiev = c("1234", 
"2341", "43", "22")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

ID   Company Name_1 Name_2  Achiev
131  ABC     Alex   Marian  1234
206  DEF     Peter  Maria   2341
5    EFD     Mila   NA      43
2    SDF     Maya   NA      22
```

I want to join the column `Achiev` to `df_1` based on the columns `ID`, `Company` and `Name`.

In my original, I have over 500 more columns in each dataframe and I want to perform this transformation for at least a couple more columns, please keep that in mind.

Comment: Try `dplyr::left_join`. It seems straightforward, see if it works.

Comment: Use `pivot_longer` on `df2` so you have a single `Name` column in `df2` too, then `left_join(df1, df2_long)`. Or write out a separate `left_join` for each `Name_*` column. Either will work.

Comment: (If you pivot longer, only bring along the columns you want to add to `df1`, not all 500)

Comment: In my original I have over 73 of these Name_ columns, how do I make sure that I don't have to type themup individually for the pivot/join?

Comment: When you pivot you can use select helpers like `starts_with("Name_")`. See the 2nd example at the `?pivot_longer` help page where they use `starts_with("wk")`. But I see you've accepted an answer---glad it's working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
# data

df_1 = structure(list(ID = c("131", "131", "206", "206", "5", "2"), 
    Company = c("ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "EFD", "SDF"), Name = c("Alex", 
    "Marian", "Peter", "Maria", "Mila", "Maya"), Degree = c("0", 
    "1", "1", "0", "1", "0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df_2 = structure(list(ID = c("131", "206", "5", "2"), Company = c("ABC", 
"DEF", "EFD", "SDF"), Name_1 = c("Alex", "Peter", "Mila", "Maya"
), Name_2 = c("Marian", "Maria", NA, NA), Achiev = c("1234", 
"2341", "43", "22")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

# left join
merge(df_1, df_2, by.x = c("ID", "Company", "Name"), by.y = c("ID", "Company", "Name_1"), all.x = TRUE)
#>    ID Company   Name Degree Name_2 Achiev
#> 1 131     ABC   Alex      0 Marian   1234
#> 2 131     ABC Marian      1   <NA>   <NA>
#> 3   2     SDF   Maya      0   <NA>     22
#> 4 206     DEF  Maria      0   <NA>   <NA>
#> 5 206     DEF  Peter      1  Maria   2341
#> 6   5     EFD   Mila      1   <NA>     43
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks but I also want to include Name_2 in the matching and in my original data I have over 73 of those name columns, how do I make sure they also match?

Comment: @Soph2010 just add matching columns in by.x and by.y as in `by.x = c("ID", "Company", "Name", "NEW COLUMN), by.y = c("ID", "Company", "Name_1", "COLUMN THAT MATCHES NEW COLUMN")`

Comment: thanks but is there any way to simplify this as I do not want to type up over 73 columns individually? They all follow the same pattern Name_1 through Name_73

Comment: @Soph2010 instead of typing one by one, you can create a list with column names as in `names_list = paste0("Name_", 1:73)` and then `by.y = c("ID", "Company", names_list)`. Also, you'd have to create a list for df_1 in order to complete matching

Answer (score 0):

I guess *Name_1* and *Name_2* have to be handled in some way, e.g. by combining *Names* of `df2`

```
Cols <- grep("^Name", colnames(df2))

df2_m <- na.omit(cbind(rbind(df2[,-Cols], df2[,-Cols]), 
                       Name = unname(unlist(df2[,Cols]))))

df2_m
   ID Company Achiev   Name
1 131     ABC   1234   Alex
2 206     DEF   2341  Peter
3   5     EFD     43   Mila
4   2     SDF     22   Maya
5 131     ABC   1234 Marian
6 206     DEF   2341  Maria
```

```
merge(df1, df2_m, c("ID", "Company", "Name"), all.x = T)
   ID Company   Name Degree Achiev
1 131     ABC   Alex      0   1234
2 131     ABC Marian      1   1234
3   2     SDF   Maya      0     22
4 206     DEF  Maria      0   2341
5 206     DEF  Peter      1   2341
6   5     EFD   Mila      1     43
```